# Trying to login to an admin using Scrapy, but it is not waiting for a redirect

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

The following code is to login into the admin panel of a site, but I'm running into a hiccup that hopefully is easy to solve.

Normally, to login, I go to example.com/login, fill out the form and hit submit, it then redirects me to example.com/authorize/, a blank page, then after 2 seconds or so, brings me to example.com/adminpanel.

What is occurring with my Scrapy code is that the form is filled and submitted, then I get

```
[scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET example.com/authorize/ >
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET example.com/authorize/ >
```

The callback is running as soon as the redirect to authorize is loaded, but what I want is it to wait a bit for it to switch to example.com/adminpanel.

Is there a way to instruct scrapy to wait for this second "redirect" to the panel?

```
class StackSpider(Spider):
    name = "stack"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://example.com/login",
    ]
    custom_settings = { 'REDIRECT_MAX_TIMES': 10, 'METAREFRESH_MAXDELAY': 3000 }

    def parse(self,response):
        logging.warning(response)
        __RequestVerificationToken = response.xpath('//*[@name="__RequestVerificationToken"]/@value').get()

        yield FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'__RequestVerificationToken': __RequestVerificationToken, 'username':'test', 'password':'test'},
            callback=self.parse_after_login
        )

    def parse_after_login(self,response):
        logging.warning(response)

        return
```

Comment: dumb question: why don't you manually navigate to the admin panel instead of waiting for the redirect?

Comment: Haha, not a dumb question. It didnt really occur to me to do that. But I'll give it a try. I wasn't sure if there was some logic in the transition from example.com/authorize/ to example.com/adminpanel

Comment: Looks like the authorize page is passing data so that's probably the issue with me not being able to access the adminpanel directly.